# How to make on Textwatcher for multiple Editext?

Tags: android

I have three Edittext named as mobile,password,email for these i was implemented seperate Textwatcher for them, But I want to make single Textwatcher for multiple Edittext.How can I do that to acheive.

code:-

```
private final TextWatcher m_EmailWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        checkForEmptyField();
    }


    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    /*check whether SoftKeyPad open or hide*/
        m_MainLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                int heightDiff = m_MainLayout.getRootView().getHeight() - m_MainLayout.getHeight();
                //noinspection StatementWithEmptyBody
                if (heightDiff > 100) { // if more than 100 pixels, its probably a keyboard...

                } else {/*if hide then clear focus from Password Edit text*/
                    m_EmailEditText.clearFocus();
                    m_Email = m_EmailEditText.getText().toString().trim();
                    if (isValidEmail(m_Email) && m_Email.split("@")[0].length() <= 64 && (m_Email.split("@")[1].length() >= 2 && m_Email.split("@")[1].length() <= 255)) {

                    } else {
                        m_EmailEditText.setError("Please enter valid Email Id");
                    }

                }
            }
        });

    }
};
private final TextWatcher m_PassWordWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        checkForEmptyField();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
};
private final TextWatcher m_MobileWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        checkForEmptyField();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate `Class` extending `TextWatcher`.

```
public class CustomTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    private EditText editText;
    private Context context;
    private int value;

    public CustomTextWatcher(Context context, EditText et, int val){
        this.context = context;
        this.editText = et;
        this.value = val;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if(s.toString().length() > 0){
            if(value == 0){
                //Email
            }
            else if(value == 1){
                //Mobile Number
            }
            else if(value == 2){
                //Password
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
}
```

Whenever you want to apply a `TextWatcher` to an `EditText` do it like this.

```
CustomTextWatcher cew1 = new CustomTextWatcher(this, emailEditText, 0);
emailEditText.addTextChangedListener(cew1);
```

Comment: but what about if i have to implement in multiple classes

Comment: and this method checkForEmptyField(); is in my class and how to add this in that custom class

Comment: You want to check the emptiness of the field? Is that what you meant?